# Laravel Eloquent model complex query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am logged in as the first student in the table. I want to retrieve a list of all the students who are within the same department as mine and whom I didn't send a request to yet, using Eloquent model.

[image]

```
//Requestt.php
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsto('App\Student','id', 'Sender_id','Rec_id');
}

//Student.php
public function requestts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Requestt', 'id');
}

public function department()
{    
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
}
```

Note: Don't mind the double "t" in requestt.

Comment: are you try eager loading ?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution**

```
// you may have the logged in student in your hand.
// for the example, I'll take the first.
$logged_in_student = Student::first();

$other_students = Student::where('department_id', $logged_in_student->department_id)
    ->whereDoesntHave('requestts', function($query) use($logged_in_student) {
        $query->where('Rec_id', $logged_in_student->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

**Explanation**

The first `where` clause is to filter students who are in the same department.
The second `whereDoesntHave` clause is to filter students who has no `requestts` from logged in student.

Answer (score 0):

here we might have two scenarios

> First one:

```
Student::where('department_id', Auth::user()->department_id)->doesntHave('requestts')->get();
```

here we are querying the student model by getting all students in the same department as the auth user.. then checking those that doesn't have requests.

> Note: IF requests table has sender and receiver ids which they are
>   referring to students table you need here to have two functions first
>   one related to the sender , the second one for the receiver.

```
requests(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Requestt', 'Rec_id');
}
```

> the second scenario is requestts table only is referring to the sender in this case you have to get students whom you already send requests then get those who doesn't have requests

```
Student::where('department_id', Auth::user()->department_id)->whereNotIn('id', Student::requestts()->pluck('Sender_id'))->get();
```

to be honest your tables name fields are a bit ambiguous, if that doesn't solve your problem, please explain more what do you need.

you can refer to [laravel docs Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)